# Add a Link to an Overlay Image

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a link to an image that has an overlay applied to it. When users hover over the image they get an opaque overlay and text appear. This works great, however I also need users to be able to click that image and taken to a link.

I have pasted my code below - the overlay works but the link portion does not. I believe it's because the overlay is interfering. I tried changing the placement of the link but was unable to do so. I am able to make the '+' be the link, but ideally the entire image should link.

Any thoughts?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm3gtf7k/)

```css
.roomphoto:hover .img__description { transform: translateY(0); }
.roomphoto .img__description_layer { top: 30px; }
.roomphoto:hover .img__description_layer { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
.img__description_layer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #cdcbca;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
    
    .roomphoto {
        height: 166px;
    }
    
    .img__description {
        transition: .2s;
        transform: translateY(1em);
        z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .overlay:after {
      position: absolute;
      content:"";
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      opacity:0;
    }
    
    .overlay:hover:after  {
      opacity: .8;
    }
    
    .blue:after {
      background-color: #1a3761;
    }
    
    .img__description a {
     color: #fff;
    }
    
    .roomselect {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .roomselect img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
    
    
    .room3 {
    width: 32%;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="roomselect"><div class="room3">
  <div class="roomphoto overlay blue">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/J9KeYkEZf4HHD5LRGf799N-650-80.jpg" alt="Image Text" />
    </a>
    <div class="img__description_layer">
      <p class="img__description">
        <span style="border-radius: 50%; width: 30px; height: 30px; padding: 0px 14px; border: 1px solid #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 36px;">+</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange your html in such a way that when you click on image, you are actually clicking on the anchor tag. I have made some changes to your html, let me know if these work. You might have to increase roomphoto height.

```
<div class="roomselect">
<div class="room3">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="roomphoto overlay blue">
  <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/J9KeYkEZf4HHD5LRGf799N-650-80.jpg" alt="Image Text" />

  <div class="img__description_layer">
    <p class="img__description"><span style="border-radius: 50%; width: 30px; height: 30px; padding: 0px 14px; border: 1px solid #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 36px;">+</span></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</a>

</div>
</div>
```